# simple conditions equation

Tags: graphics, equations, tikz-arrows

I tested some solutions, but without getting the simple results.
aesthetic I would like to use the arrows. rather than parentheses. the formula is followed by a text with explanations of the conditions.
would you have some simple suggestions about it?
thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{5}{4}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{6}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$
\alpha = m\frac{l'\,z}{l_{0}}\;
\begin{cases}
>0\\=0\\<0
\end{cases}
$

$
\alpha = m\frac{l'\,z}{l_{0}}
\begin{array}{c}
\nearrow >0\\
\rightarrow = 0\\
\searrow < 0\\
\end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

------------**UPDATE**------------------

this is what I wanted to get :

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{minipage}{.32\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{equation}
            \begin{aligned}
            P_{G} = \frac{1}{\rho_{z}}gz_{,i}(\overline{\rho'u_{i}'})\label{eq097.4a}
            \end{aligned}
            \end{equation}
        \end{minipage}\hfil
        \begin{minipage}{.30 \textwidth}
            %\centering
            \begin{equation}
            \begin{aligned}
            P_{G} = \frac{1}{\rho_{z}}g(\overline{\rho' w'})\label{eq097.4b}
            \end{aligned}
            \end{equation}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{.35 \textwidth}
            \begin{equation}
            \begin{aligned}
            P_{G} = g\frac{\overline{\theta' w'}}{\theta_{0}}\label{eq097.4c}\;
            \begin{array}{c@{\;}l}
            &>0\\[-.75ex]
            \nearrow\\ 
            \rightarrow &= 0\\
            \searrow\\[-.5ex]
            &< 0
            \end{array}
            \end{aligned}
            \end{equation}
        \end{minipage}%\hfill
    \end{subequations}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post an example of the kind of text you'd like to add?

Comment: so far i not see anywhere your second example for writing "condition equation". `cases` is normal for such cases. it is far more readable than your "invention" ...

Comment: @Bernard the equation I would like to explain is more complex. It is the conditions with respect to the production of buoyancy forces compared to the Richardson number.
I am not very familiar with the tikz library and often I have difficulty with trivial things (which are often the most important ones)

Comment: @Bernard in this case it is only an aesthetic problem. I prefer the arrows, to the braces

Comment: Would there be an explanation per case, or a global explanation?

Comment: @Bernard the formula is explained globally and as the conditions change in the sign, its relationship with mechanical production varies.  the relationship between floating forces and mechanical production, returning the Richardson number

Comment: You might put the explanations in a `\parbox` on the right of your formula.

Comment: @Bernard the comments concerning the equation will be inserted as normal text on a subsequent page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two columns in the `array` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$
\alpha = m\frac{l'\,z}{l_{0}}
\begin{array}{c@{\;}l}
  &>0\\[-.75ex]
  \nearrow\\ 
  \rightarrow &= 0\\
  \searrow\\[-.5ex]
  &< 0
\end{array}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this could be an excellent and simple solution

Comment: My compliment also to you. (+1)

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion for example, for the 2nd formula, without left bracket, is with the package `tikz-cd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=.4cm, column sep=.5cm]
& >0 \\
{\alpha = m\dfrac{l'\,z}{l_{0}}}
\arrow[ru] \arrow[r] \arrow[rd] & =0 \\
& <0
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is a good solution, but I need to enter the equation number

Comment: @Antonio Thank you for that. Sorry for English (I'm like you Italian but in English I'm a landslide :-() but you could adapt my code very well, for example, reducing with the option row sep or column sep the length of the vectors to have a result very similar to what you want to get. Try changing the centimetres in the two options.

Answer (score 3):

Done here with two separate stacks, so that the arrow vertical gap can be different than the baselineskip of the conditions stack.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{5}{4}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{6}{5}
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{6}
\makeatother
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\arrowstack{\,\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{\Sstackgap}{%
    \stackengine{\Sstackgap}{\rightarrow}{\nearrow}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}%
  }{\searrow}{U}{c}{F}{F}{S}%
}}
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{L}{16pt}% GOVERNS THE CONDITIONS STACK BASELINESKIP
\setstackgap{S}{2pt}% GOVERNS THE ARROW STACK GAP
\alpha = m\frac{l'\,z}{l_{0}}
\arrowstack
\Centerstack[l]{{}>0\\{}=0\\{}<0}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yours is a particular solution. I always have problems with `\stackMath`. I got errors with solutions that use this line several times. I think it's due to my not very professional preamble

Comment: @Antonio `\stackMath` is a **global** declaration switch.  By default, or after a `\stackText`, stacking is done in text mode.  With with the `\stackMath` switch set, it is done in math mode.  If all your stacking is done in math, you need only set it once in the preamble.  If you stack often enough so that some stacks are in text and others are in math, I recommend letting the default stay in text mode and wrapping math stacks in `\ensurestackMath{...}`.